# PHP SplObserver Class seems to behave differently on Centos 5 and Centos 7

Tags: php, centos

I have a site which uses the SplObserver class to add events and then notify various users by email about those events.

However, I am having a problem with the code:

```
/**
 * Attach a Observer to Offer
 * @param SplObserver $obs Observer instance
 *
 * return void
 */
public function attach(SplObserver $obs)
{
    $id = spl_object_hash($obs);
    $this->observers[$id] = $obs;
}

/**
 * Remove a Observer to Offer
 * @param SplObserver $obs Observer instance
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function detach(SplObserver $obs)
{
    $id = spl_object_hash($obs);
    unset($this->observers[$id]);
}

/**
 * Notify attached Observer
 */
public function notify()
{
    if ($this->observers) {
        foreach ($this->observers as $obs) {
            $this->detach($obs);
            $obs->update($this);
        }
    }
    $this->lastEvent = null;
}

public function prepareCommonObservers(MyPDO $DB, Core_Context $context, $extraInfo=null)
{
    //Mails
    require_once ('class/contrib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $notificator = new MailNotificator(new PHPMailer(),new FileReader(),$context);
    $mailObs = OfferObserver_OfferMail::getInstance($this->type(), $context, $notificator, $DB);
    $mailObs->extraInfo=$extraInfo;
    $this->attach($mailObs);

    //Business Listing Limits
    $keyObs = new OfferObserver_BusinessLimitObserver($context, $notificator, $DB);
    $this->attach($keyObs);

    //Keywords
    $keyObs = new OfferObserver_KeywordObserver($context, $notificator, $DB);
    $this->attach($keyObs);

    //Banned Words
    $bannedWordObs = new OfferObserver_BannedWordsObserver($DB);
    $this->attach($bannedWordObs);

    //Final value fee
    if ($this->item->user->businessSeller) {
        $finalFee = BusinessFee::getInstanceFromDB($DB, 'offer/finalValue', $this->originalSiteId, $context->siteOptions['currentChargeStructure']);
    } else {
        $finalFee = Fee::getInstanceFromDB($DB, 'offer/finalValue', $this->originalSiteId, $context->siteOptions['currentChargeStructure']);
    }
    if ($finalFee->active) {
        $finalValueObs = new OfferObserver_FinalValueFeeObserver($context, $notificator, $DB);
        $this->attach($finalValueObs);
    }

    //Auction Item queue
    $itemQueueObs = new OfferObserver_AuctionQueue($DB);
    $this->attach($itemQueueObs);
}
```

In particular, for two sites running the same code on Centos 5, I have had to alter the original:

```
public function notify()
{
    if ($this->observers) {
        foreach ($this->observers as $obs) {
            $obs->update($this);
        }
    }
}
```

to read:

```
public function notify()
{
    if ($this->observers) {
        foreach ($this->observers as $obs) {
            $this->detach($obs);
            $obs->update($this);
        }
    }
    $this->lastEvent = null;
}
```

Without this change, I was often getting duplicated emails sent out.  Both servers are running Centos 5.11, although different PHP versions (5.5 and 5.6).

However, on another site running on Centos 7 (PHP 5.6), I have to revert to the original function, otherwise emails are not sent out...

Any suggestions as to what may be happening?

Comment: You may want to check the changelog for 5.5->5.6 to confirm there were no changes to SplObserver.

Also you have `$keyObs = new OfferObserver_BusinessLimitObserver` and `$keyObs = new OfferObserver_KeywordObserver`.  That _shouldn't_ cause a problem because in theory you're reassigning the variable but if you're hitting an edge case where you're attaching the same object twice, that would explain the duplicate emails.

Comment: Don't think it can be the difference in PHP 5.5 to 5.6 as one of the sites which duplicates emails is running 5.6

Tried renaming the second $keyObs, but unfortunately, same result, I still get duplicate emails if I comment out the $this->detach($obs);

Comment: Try debugging the object hashes to make sure the hashes aren't being reused.  Per [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php), _Once the object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects_.

Comment: Correction - Yes they are being reused - I see a total of 18 hashes go through the notify() function for some reason (there are only a total of 6 events attached).  I see the first 6 events are sent, and then notify gets called again with the same 6 events plus another 6 (with unique hashes)  - odd as the notify is only being called once by my code!

Comment: I think it may be the way you're doing notify().  Per the docs for SplObserver::update(), _This method is called when any SplSubject to which the observer is attached calls SplSubject::notify()_.  So it sounds like the way you've got your notify function defined may be the problem.  You call `notify()` which calls `update()` automatically and then you call `update()` again in your notify function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me is to ensure that at the end of the update() function all of the observers are nullified - it is interesting that this change was not needed on Centos 7 - I wonder why?

```
public function notify()
{
    if ($this->observers) {
        foreach ($this->observers as $obs) {
            $obs->update($this);
        }
    }
    $this->observers = null;
}
```